# How to deploy a Django/Tornado based web app that's built with platter?

Tags: python, django, git, deployment, tornado

This question is mostly about the technical details + some best practices of how to efficiently deploy a python web app that's built using platter.

Taking Django for instance, I have a project that's already built into a tarball distribution. This includes all wheels of all deps + the package of the app itself.

My repo directory also contains some other files that need to be distributed with the deployed code, such as: `manage.py`, a `fabfile` package with fabric utils, and some configuration files (for supervisor, nginx, etc).

So my questions are:

1. How can I wrap these extra files into the distribution that contains the project?
2. If I simply use git to clone/pull the project on the server I have these files, but then I have duplicate of the source code being both in the project and zipped in the tarball. How can I avoid that? Committing the tarball into a separate repo?
3. Perhaps the duplication is not so bad, and I'll end up with multiple tarballs in my `dist/` directory and only one symlinked to the `current` from which I deploy?

Same goes for a Tornado based app.

Answer (score 0):

My first rule of deployment is "whatever works". Every production environment has different requirements. But to give opinions on your questions:

1. Not everything should be in your Python project. Perhaps there is a way to do it, but I think it's using the wrong hammer.
2. You can create a separate Git repo that handles configuration and asset files for your production deployment (this does not even be managed by Git if you don't care about old, irrelevant configuration files). This does not have to be a Python project, just the files for the production deployment. You may optionally put a Python script or two in here (or just a README.txt or fab files or a Buildout config) to automate tasks such as unpacking your platter or copying config files around.

   It's tempting (and possible) to put production config things in your main Git repo. This is even suggested by apps that create boilerplate files for development and production configuration. This doesn't mean it's the best way to do things though.

   My rule is that the main Git repo is "development only". It's cloned by developers who are setting up and working in development environments. It conflates a Python project far too much to try and be an Python application and also be a place to manage a production system, IMHO.

   Production is managed separately. Sometimes by people different from the developers or at least the developer is wearing a different hat when thinking about a production deployment. This way you can also have a small, clean repo  that tracks just changes to your production system.
3. Playing with symlinks within a single deployment that represents different builds is an extra layer of confusion. And the impetus to do so comes from trying to do everything from a single Python project.

   Deploy your python application to something like /var/myapp/build-2015-10-29/. Then create a symlink at /var/myapp/current/ that points to this location. This way you can create a full deployment at /var/myapp/build-2015-11-05/ and tweak the config to start on a separate port, bring the app up and ensure everything works, then just switch from the symlink from the old build to the new build with minimal downtime.

Comment: 1. that is for sure, I'm working towards being 12-factors-compliant. 2. Same as #1, but not clear about your bottom line, you saying have a separate repo for deployment? 3. What I meant is what you wrote below, see here http://platter.pocoo.org/dev/quickstart/#installing-platter-packages. So bottom line is not clear...